# Unable to fetch core data with condition like SQL

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

let I have a Core Data Database in swift ios 
I have one Entity:"Player"
In this entity, there are three row.
"Player_id", "Player_name", "Team_name"

## And successfully save data in this structure.

My Problem is 
I want to fetch data with query like sql
I want to fetch like this

```
where (Team_name == "Barcelona")

{

array = [player_name(index.row)]

}
```

Please help me guys.

My Fetching code is not correct yet. I searched on google and found this

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Player")

// Add Sort Descriptor
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "team_name", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

// Add Predicate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "team_name CONTAINS[c] %@", "Barcelona")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

do {
    let records = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]

    for record in records {
        print(record.value(forKey: "player_name") ?? "no name")
    }

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: can you share the fetch request code ?

Comment: Jok3r, updated in question.

Comment: You need to use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate for fetching filtered data

Comment: what  result you getting ?

Comment: It's not running. Getting error. I'm fresher. Please give me a sample code which suitable in this situation

Comment: add your entity structure

Answer (score 0):

Predicates and sort descriptors are case sensitive.

If the attribute is `Team_name` the sort descriptor and predicate must be

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Team_name", ascending: true)

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Team_name CONTAINS[c] %@", "Barcelona")
```

and also

```
print(record.value(forKey: "Player_name") ?? "no name")
```